# In Water Solution will there be an interaction between Ozone Gas and Carbonic Acid

Tags: organic-chemistry

**Original Question Posted 8/31/15**
We are trying to predict what will happen when Carbon Dioxide gas is introduced into a contact chamber that serves as an Ozone Contact Chamber.  These Contact chambers presently oxidize compounds found in Municipal Pool Water along with Chlorine at below 5ppm. there are 3 contact chambers (one for each pool) and the Temperature range is from 104 to 80 F. We are switching from Hydrochloric acid to Carbon Dioxide to keep the Total Alkalinity from dropping when the acid is introduced.

```
"Predict what will happen" is exceptionally broad. If you can narrow your question to specifics, that will help a great deal. For instance, we don't know what the compounds are in the municipal pool water. See this link for a guide to asking questions here on chemistry.SE. –  Todd Minehardt yesterday    
Ozone and carbon dioxide will be pretty much indifferent to each other. Indeed, ozone is known for its ability to oxidize almost everything, but CO  2   is already a final product of oxidation. "What is dead may never die", they say. Likewise, CO  2   may never be oxidized. –  Ivan Neretin yesterday
```

Thank you for taking the time to respond Todd and Ivan. The other compounds in the municipal pool water would include body oils, salt from perspiration and whatever else a particular bather might introduce. We are using Calcium Hypochlorite as a chlorine source and, depending on the PH may also leach Calcium from the Plaster of Pool Walls. The calcium harness varies in the Three separate bodies of water from 400 to 1200 and we endeavor to keep the PH between 7.2 and 7.6.  The Total Alkalinity is around 20 in the 2 bodies of water in which the PH is controlled by adding Hydrochloric acid. We have started using Carbon Dioxide in our smallest body of water and are introducing it in the water returning to the pool perhaps 150 ft away the Total Alkalinity in that pool has risen to 120 ppm which helps to maintain a more stable PH.  Because the piping to the other 2 pools is not as long we are thinking about introducing the Carbon Dioxide into the line the ozone is injected into before the contact chambers. Ivan stated that the Carbon Dioxide would not interact with the ozone.  My research implies that both Carbonic Acid (the objective of injecting Carbon Dioxide) and Ozone are very unstable, and Carbonic Acid has a very short life.  **Is it likely that the Carbonic Acid would interact with the Ozone before the Carbonic Acid can effect a PH change (in effect neutralizing both objectives)?**        Thank you  for any feedback you may provide.